# Run value through function

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I have the following management command in Django which updates a record with data from an external source:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **options):

    field_mappings = {
        'first_name': 'Voornaam',
        'initials': 'Voorletters',
        'last_name_prefix': 'Voorvoegsel',
        'last_name': 'Achternaam',
        'sex': 'Geslacht',
        'DOB': ['Geboortedatum', 'convert_DOB'],
        'street': 'Straat',
        'house_number': 'Huisnummer',
        'zipcode': 'Postcode',
        'city': 'Woonplaats',
        'country': 'Land',
        'phone_number': 'Telefoonnummer',
        'phone_number_mobile': 'MobielTelefoonnummer',
        'email_address': 'Emailadres',
        'insurer_name': 'NaamVerzekeraar',
        'insurance_policy_number': 'PolisnummerVerzekering',
        'gp_name': 'NaamHuisarts',
    }

    patients = Patient.objects.all()
    for patient in patients:
        result = Query(patient.pharmacy, 'patient_by_bsn', {'BSN': patient.BSN}).run()
        for x, y in field_mappings.items():
            if type(y) == list:
                pass
            else:
                setattr(patient, x, result[y]['0'])
        patient.save()
        print('Patient {}-{} updated'.format(patient.pharmacy.vv_id, patient.vv_id))

@staticmethod
def convert_DOB(value):
    return timezone.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(value).date()
```

Most fields can be saved without converting the data first, but some fields like the DOB need converting (in this case from a UNIX timestamp to a Python `datetime.date`). Where it currently says `pass` underneath `if type(y) == list` I want to run the value through the listed function first so that it would save `convert_DOB(value)` instead of the original value - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your mapping don't use the name of the conversion function but the function itself, ie:

```
def convert_DOB(dob):
    # your code here


# ...

 field_mappings = {
    # ...
    'DOB': ['Geboortedatum', convert_DOB],
    # ...
    }
```

Then you just have to pass your value to the function and retrieve the result:

```
     for attrname, sourcekey in field_mappings.items():

        if isinstance(sourcekey, list):
            # unpack the list (assumes length 2)
            sourcekey, converter = key
            value = result[sourcekey]['0']
            # convert the value
            value = converter(value)  
        else:
            # no conversion needed
            value = result[sourcekey]['0']

        # done
        setattr(patient, attrname, value)
```

Note that from a purely semantic POV you should be using a tuple not a list - a list is supposed to be an homogenous collection where position is not significant, a tuple is an heterogenous collection where poistion is significant. In your case the position is indeed significant since the first item is the key to the results dict and the second the conversion function.

Also the way you use `field_mappings` suggests you could replace it with a list of (attrname, key_or_key_converter) tuples since you only iterate over the dict's (key, value) pairs.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Only thing I had to change was to use `self.convert_DOB` in the tuple instead of just `convert_DOB`.

Comment: Using the function directly in the mapping is definitely the better approach, I am deleting my answer.